# At the research of some folklore russian accordion tunes

Tags: styles, ethnomusicology, folk, accordion

The other day I was watching a video documentary about the discovering of frozen mammoths in the Siberian tundra. At some moment there was a tune in I really enjoyed.

It was mainly accordion, rather fast, and the theme was on a scale really similar to: `E-F-G#-A-B-C-D#`, (really looks like an Arabic maqam though)

I was sure I could find similar tunes searching in the `Russian polka style`...
However... I was wrong or not lucky enough. The tunes I have found on youtube are much more slow or melancholic: they don't convey the energy and trance-like repeated anthem.

Within the accordion style that I search for, one could imagine some Cossack soldiers screaming oy! from time to time, it would perfectly fit the Russian cliché that this kind of tunes convey.

Do you know what other Slavic folklore music styles I should check ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for one, there are many more cultures in Russia than just Russians. If it's Siberian you're looking for, then search for that. And other regions nearby. There's also some musical overlap between Siberian, Mongolian, and Tuvan folk styles.

"Peoples of Russia" is a good search term for general ethnographic information. There have been several books with that title.